# Show hidden bootboxjs dialog

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootbox

I create a modal dialog via **bootboxjs**, with option `show: false`

```
  bootbox.dialog({
    message: "Whatever",
    show: false,
  });
```

How can I then show that dialog (e.g. on a click event)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Bootbox before, but after looking at the source, you add the `data-bb="dialog"` attribute onto the button. Then, define a click function at the top of your script:

**Note:** I am using `demo` namespace. I saw it in the source they were using on the page. So change this

```
$(function() {
    var demos = {}; // object namespace

    $(document).on("click", "a[data-bb]", function(e) { // all buttons that have this attribute
        e.preventDefault();
        var type = $(this).data("bb"); // get what type it is (alert, dialog, etc.)

        if (typeof demos[type] === 'function') {
            demos[type](); // run that type (demos.alert(), demos.dialog(), etc.)
        }
    });

    demos.dialog = function() {
       bootbox.dialog({
          message: "Whatever"
       });
    };
});
```

Hope this helps in some way